# Install Startup Disk Creator error from Ubuntu Software on Ubuntu 18.0.4 minimal installation version

Tags: startup-disk-creator

Unable to install Startup Disk Creator as download failed: E: http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 usb-creator-gtk amd64 0.3.5 is not (yet) available (Unsupported proxy configured: 127.0.0.1://37809)

Comment: 1. Please describe how you tried to install `usb-creator-gtk`, the command you used; 2. Can you install other programs, or update & upgrade your Ubuntu? -- 3. Maybe there is a problem with your connection via the internet (if you must connect via a proxy).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

Try to manually install it on command line `sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk`.
The application is installed and you can find it on "Show Applications", or manually execute it via `usb-creator-gtk`.